# Loading/Saving a map<map, torch::Tensor>> object in LibTorch for fast read/write

Tags: serialization, libtorch

My use case is I have a C++ object of type `map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>>` which I want to serialize, with two functions

```
#include <torch/torch.h>

using namespace std;

void save_tensor_map(map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> m, string fp) {
    // 
}

map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> read_tensor_map(string fp) {
    //
}
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I am not aware of any library which would do it easily, you will need to iterate over your map and serialize the key and tensor storage for each pair. In a tensor, the `data_ptr()` function returns a pointer to the underlying data array so it's easy to write in a file. Reciprocally you can use `from_blob` to build a tensor from a pointer. Is there something that is specifically blocking you ?

Comment: @trialNerror are you saying I'd need to have a separate file for each tensor? I'd be fine simply iterating and writing tensors with keyword if they can be written to the same file. If they all have to be separate files that would be not great.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. You can have it in a single file, no problem. You can iterate over all key/value pairs and write them in a binary file, you just need to be careful to save all the metadata (scalar type, dimensions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my attempt at writing your map in a file. I think you can deduce the read function from it. I don't have a compiler at hand right now to test it, please tell me if it raises issues.

```
void save_tensor_map(const std::map<std::string, torch::Tensor>& map, const std::string& filename) {
  auto out_file = std::fstream(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  for(auto itr = map.begin(); itr != map.end(); ++itr) {
    // writing the key
    auto key = itr->first;
    size_t size = key.size();
    out_file.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
    out_file.write(&key[0], size);    

    // Writing tensor metadata
    auto tensor = itr->second;
    const at::IntArrayRef& sizes = tensor.sizes();
    int64_t nb_dims = sizes.size();
    out_file.write((char*)&nb_dims, sizeof(nb_dims));
    out_file.write((char*)&sizes[0], sizeof(long)*nb_dims);

    int64_t scalar_type = static_cast<int64_t>(tensor.scalar_type());
    out_file.write((char*)&scalar_type, sizeof(scalar_type));

    int64_t elem_size = tensor.element_size();
    out_file.write((char*)&elem_size, sizeof(elem_size));

    // writing tensor data
    out_file.write((char*)tensor.data_ptr(), elem_size*tensor.numel());
  }
}
```

In the read function you'll probably need to call `torch::from_blob(void* data_ptr, const at::IntArrayRef& tensor_sizes, const at::TensorOptions& options) -> torch::Tensor` to deserialize the tensor, but otherwise it's the same structure

Edit : Just realized you can also make the tensor serialization much simpler with the `save` and `load` which convert to/from a stringstream (which is easy to read/write itself). See [there](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19025#issuecomment-482308272)

Comment: I think your original approach might be the way to go, since you can only invoke torch::save once. The docs says :"std::ostringstream stream;
///   // Note that the same stream cannot be used in multiple torch::save(...)
///   // invocations, otherwise the header will be corrupted."

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <torch/torch.h>

using namespace std;

void save_tensor_map(map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> m, string fp) {
    auto out_file = std::fstream(fp, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    for (map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>>::iterator outer_iter = m.begin(); outer_iter != m.end(); ++outer_iter) {
        string outer_key = outer_iter->first;
        map<string, torch::Tensor> inner_map = m[outer_key];
        for (map<string, torch::Tensor>::iterator inner_iter = inner_map.begin(); inner_iter != inner_map.end(); ++inner_iter) {
            string inner_key = inner_iter->first;
            torch::Tensor t = inner_map[inner_key];
            
            // writing the key
            string key_to_write = outer_key + "$" + inner_key;
            size_t key_size = key_to_write.size();
            out_file.write((char*)&key_size, sizeof(key_size));
            out_file.write(&key_to_write[0], key_size);

            // writing tensor metadata
            const at::IntArrayRef& sizes = t.sizes();
            int64_t nb_dims = sizes.size();
            
            // number of dimensions
            out_file.write((char*)&nb_dims, sizeof(nb_dims));
            
            // size per dimension
            for (int i = 0; i < nb_dims; i++) {
                out_file.write((char*)&sizes[i], sizeof(long));
            }
            
            // scalar type
            int64_t scalar_type = static_cast<int64_t>(t.scalar_type());
            out_file.write((char*)&scalar_type, sizeof(scalar_type));
            
            // size of each element in the tensor
            int64_t elem_size = t.element_size();
            out_file.write((char*)&elem_size, sizeof(elem_size));

            // number of elements in the tensor
            int64_t num_el = t.numel();
            out_file.write((char*)&num_el, sizeof(num_el));

            // write tensor data
            out_file.write((char*)t.data_ptr(), elem_size * num_el);
        }
    }
    out_file.close();
}

map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> read_tensor_map(string fp) {
    auto in_file = std::fstream(fp, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> m;
    while (in_file.peek() != EOF) {
        // read the metadata
        size_t key_size;
        in_file.read((char *) & key_size, sizeof(key_size));
        
        // read the key
        vector<char> c;
        for (int i = 0; i < key_size; i++) {
            char temp;
            in_file.read(&temp, sizeof(char));
            c.push_back(temp);
        }
        string key = string(c.begin(), c.end());
        int dollar_sign_pos = key.find("$");
        string left_key = key.substr(0, dollar_sign_pos);
        string right_key = key.substr(dollar_sign_pos + 1);
        
        if (m.count(left_key) == 0) {
            m[left_key] = map<string, torch::Tensor>();
        }

        // read the number of dimensions
        int64_t nb_dims;
        in_file.read((char*)&nb_dims, sizeof(nb_dims));
        
        // get a vector of the dimensions
        at::IntArrayRef int_ref;
        vector<int64_t> dims;
        for (int i = 0; i < nb_dims; i++) {
            long dim;
            in_file.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(long));
            dims.push_back((int64_t) dim);
        }
        int_ref = at::IntArrayRef(dims);

        // get the scalar type
        int64_t scalar_type;
        in_file.read((char*)&scalar_type, sizeof(scalar_type));

        // get the element size
        int64_t elem_size;
        in_file.read((char*)&elem_size, sizeof(elem_size));

        // number of elements
        int64_t num_els;
        in_file.read((char*)&num_els, sizeof(num_els));

        // read the tensor
        torch::Tensor t;
        void* data_ptr;
        data_ptr = malloc(elem_size * num_els);
        in_file.read((char*)data_ptr, elem_size * num_els);
        t = torch::from_blob(data_ptr, int_ref);
        cout << t[0];
        m[left_key][right_key] = t;
    }
    return m;
}


int main() {
    // example useage
    string outer_key_example1 = "outer_key1";
    string inner_key_example1 = "inner_key1";
    string outer_key_example2 = "outer_key2";
    string inner_key_example2 = "inner_key2";
    map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> outer_map;
    map<string, torch::Tensor> inner_map1;
    inner_map1[inner_key_example1] = torch::ones({ 5, 5 });
    outer_map[outer_key_example1] = inner_map1;
    map<string, torch::Tensor> inner_map2;
    inner_map2[inner_key_example2] = torch::zeros({ 5, 5 });
    outer_map[outer_key_example2] = inner_map2;
    string fp = "C:/Users/james/example_file";
    save_tensor_map(outer_map, fp);
    map<string, map<string, torch::Tensor>> read_map;
    read_map = read_tensor_map(fp);
}
```